# What meta tags can I use on my page to stop it getting indexed?

Tags: html

Are there any meta tags for this? I keep getting google index my logon and register pages. I tried putting something in the robots.txt but it doesn't seem to have checked that for a while. Just want to be sure and add a meta tag if there is one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Would cause the page to not get indexed and links would not be followed by the crawler.

However, its up to the search engine's algorithm to decide whether it will use this information as intended by you. There are no guarantees for this meta tag or robots.txt

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) entry, not meta tags. You can then exclude explict resource paths, i.e.:

```
# robots.txt for http://www.example.com/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /login.html
Disallow: /register.html
```

Add this text to a file called "robots.txt" and put it in the root of your site.